# GQL not returning results

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, express-graphql

I'm practicing GQL, I've issue while displaying the data in `Playground`.

I trying to hit the jsonplaceholder api, to retrieve all posts and display them but it throws the following error.

```
error: GRAPHQL_FORMAT_ERROR: Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.allPosts.
```

**Request:**

```
{
  allPosts {
    id
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
      "errors": [
        {
          "extensions": {
            "code": "400"
          }
        }
      ],
      "data": {
        "allPosts": null
      }
    }
```

Below is my Schema `Posts.graphql`

```
#Description of Post

type Post {
  userId: Int
  id: Int
  title: String
  body: String
}
```

**query.graphql**

```
type Query {
  dangerousGoods: DangerousGoodsCIO
  allCourses: [Course]
  course(id: Int!): Course
  allPosts: [Post]
}
```

**query.ts**

```
export const Query: QueryResolvers.Resolvers = {
  async allPosts(_, _args, { injector }: ModuleContext) {
    const response = await injector.get(Api).getAllPosts();

    return response.body;
  }
};
```

**api.ts**

```
 getAllPosts() {
    const config = {
      uri: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,
      method: 'GET'
    };
    return this.request({ config, log: 'getAllPosts' })
    .then(response => {
      const allPost = response.json();
      return allPost;
    });
  }
```

**Note:** I could able to see the results if I mock the response like below.

So if I hardcode the post data, then it works as expected, but not working when I hit from the API.

Please tell me what im doing wrong over here.

```
public postsData = [...]

  getAllPosts () {
    return this.postsData;
  }
```

Comment: If this code uses a library like `graphql-modules`, which it looks like it does, it would be worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: I guess the question for me is what is `this.request`. It looks like it's using `fetch` under the hood, but if that's the case, why is your resolver getting the `body` property of the object returned by `response.json()`?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Rearden is right about the mention of using a fetch library. You need just more carefully take a look at the docs: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

`json()` method returns Promise to JSON, not JSON itself, so you just need to resolve it first.

Also, as you're using async/await in `query.ts` it might be worth to keep the same approach of working with Promises and rewrite your `api.ts`

```
async getAllPosts() {
    const config = {
      uri: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,
      method: 'GET'
    };
    const response = await this.request({ config, log: 'getAllPosts' })
    const allPost = await response.json();
    return allPost;
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `error: GRAPHQL_FORMAT_ERROR: response.json is not a function {"timestamp":"2019-01-28T05:30:15.065Z"}
`

Comment: Strange, how did you do it before with Promise object?